# Which integers have inverses with respect to lcm operator, a*b=lcm (a,b)

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, least-common-multiple

I know that the identity of this operator is 1, but am not sure about the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

What does it mean to say that $m$ is the inverse of $n$ with respect to that operation? It means that $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)=1$. So, your question becomes:

> For which integers $n$ is there an integer $m$ such that $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)=1$?

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, only those two elements whose lcm is 1 are inverses.

Comment: But if am correct only lcm(1,1)=1.

Comment: So, is 1 the only such integer?? Plz correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @pragyaJain What about $-1$?

Comment: But, lcm(-1,-1)=-1

Comment: @pragyaJain If you use that convenion then, yes, only $1$ has an inverse (which is $1$ again).

Comment: What now am thinking is that, what will be the lcm(1,-1)?

Comment: @pragyaJain It's up to you to tell me what you think it is. For me, the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of two non-zero integers is always a natural number.